# Edges for field of values interval

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a hermitian matrix , then field of values is defined as $F(A)=\left\{x^{*}Ax:x^{*}x=1\right\}$. We can see that $F(A)$ is closed and bounded interval because it's a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ , also it contains all the eigenvalues of matrix $A$ (so it will also contain the min and max eigenvalue).

But how can we prove that $F(A)=[a,b]$ has $a=\lambda_{min}$ and $b=\lambda_{max}$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that $F(A)$ is an interval is not due to compactness but due to convexity.

Since $A$ is hermitian, $A=UDU^*$, with $U$ unitary and $D$ diagonal with the eigenvalues of $A$ in its diagonal. Then $F(A)=F(D)$. And 
$$
x^*Dx=\sum_jD_{jj}|x_j|^2=\sum_j\lambda_j|x_j|^2. 
$$
As $\sum_j|x_j|^2=1$, 
$$
\lambda_\min=\sum_j\lambda_\min|x_j|^2\leq\sum_j\lambda_j|x_j|^2\leq\sum_j\lambda_\max|x_j|^2=\lambda_\max. 
$$

Comment: Connectedness, compactness, and the fact that $x^*Ax$ is real-valued for Hermitian $A$ are the reasons $F(A)$ is an interval.

Comment: Thank you very much , also do you have any good book to suggest for  field of values ??

Comment: The most common name is "numerical range".

Comment: Numerical range is preferred by the functional analysis community. Field of values is preferred by the matrix analysis community. Horn and Johnson's Topics in Matrix Analysis is a good introduction for FOV or NR whichever you call it.

Comment: @chhro: mathscinet returns 49 results for "field of values" and 656 for "numerical range", including many many papers in LAA, LMA, and Siam J. Matrix Anal. Appl.